# Blocking folder from Google bot with .htaccess

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I wish to block a specific folder and all its contents from Googlebot.

The folder will be called /folder/ and I will be placing it in the root directory /

I have this here:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```

I have tried to change the last line to:

```
RewriteRule ^/folder(.*)?$ - [R=403,L]
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 3):

Without the `/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder - [F,L]
```